# Width and height images in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new in JQuery and I have a small question.. I have a image-gallery I use Swiper.js for the scroll but I would like get width and height for each image depending of, for example click or swipe (ipad) for apply different styles for each image.

Here the code: http://cdpn.io/dLkHE

I´m sorry for my bad english :_( and thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: You have to add an onload handler to make sure the images are loaded.

Comment: Please include the relevant code here as well.

Comment: ok onload isn´t loaded because I think isn´t relevant for the question, with the indicated code I have only width and height of the first photo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Image height or width by this

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```